# Constructing the set $D$ that satisfies the equation $f(x)=x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, functional-equations

Let, $f:A\rightarrow B$, where $ A, B ⊆ \mathbb R$ and $f(f(x))=f(x)+1$ holds $\forall x\in A$.

I want to construct the set $D$, such that $f(x)=x+1$ holds, $\forall x\in D$.

Substituting $f(x)\mapsto x$ we have,

$$f(x)=x+1$$

Then, let $B'⊆  B$ be an image set of $f$. Hence, we can write

$$f(x)=x+1$$

holds if and only if $$x\in  D := A∩ B' .$$

Do I think correctly?

Comment: What are the sets $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon most likely subset of real numbers.

Comment: I think, complex analysis is probably not related to my question

Comment: Perhaps better use plain capital letters $A, B, C, \ldots$ for your sets. The “blackboard bold” letters are usually used for well-known sets like $\Bbb Z$ (integers), $\Bbb R$ (real numbers), or $\Bbb C$ (complex numbers).

Comment: C clearly contains that intersection. Whether its equal to that is less clear.

Comment: using $\mathbb C$ for something other than the complex numbers is a very poor idea.  What is $1$?  What is $+$?  Is $\mathbb B$ the sort of thing you can add in?  Is $\mathbb B$ contained in $\mathbb A$?

Comment: Is the following an accurate interpretation of your problem? We have a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and sets $A,B\subseteq R$ such that for all $x\in A$, $f(x) \in B$ and $f(f(x)) = f(x) + 1$. Find the set $C = \{x\in\mathbb R | f(x) = x+1\}$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog exactly, you are right.

Comment: @MartinR Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, don't use Blackboard Bold fonts. $\Bbb A$ and $\Bbb D$ already have standard meanings.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks. What is the meaning of $\mathbb A$?

Comment: The set of algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in A$ and $y=f(x),$ in order that $1+f(x)=f(f(x))=f(y)$ we must have $f(x)=y\in dom(f)=A.$ So if $B'=\{f(x):x\in A\}$ then $B'\subseteq A.$ So $B'\cap A=B'.$ Hence $B'\subseteq D.$ But we may have $B'\ne D$.

Example 1. Let $A=[0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for all $x\in A.$ Then $D=A\ne [1,\infty)=B'.$

Example 2. Let $A=\{-2\}\cup [0,\infty).$ Let $f(-2)=1.$ Let $f(x)=x+1$ for $x\ge 0.$ Then $A\ne D =[0,\infty)\ne B'= [1,\infty).$

Comment: Your examples start with $f(x)=x+1, \forall x\in A$. But, my statement starts with $f(f(x))=f(x)+1, \forall x\in A$

Comment: @User . My examples satisfy $\forall x\in A(f(f(x))=f(x)+1).$ Example 2 does not satisfy $\forall x\in A(f(x)=x+1).$ The examples are to show that we may have $A=D\ne B'$ or $A\ne D\ne B'$.